# Estimation of intubation time

Tags: mimic-iii

If I would need the estimated time of intubation for our project, what would be a good proxy. I have found several ventilation-related codes in the MIMIC-III GitHub repo (https://github.com/MIT-LCP/mimic-code).

The duration (beginning and ending) of ventilation seem to be estimated based on a number of ventilation setting. So is it right for me to estimate the time of intubation as the beginning time of ventilation?

Comment: To add above,
That makes sense if the unit is SICU or TICU... but in usual MICU the time would be fairly reasonable to estimate with vent setting interval (+/-15mins?). I agree that, though, the estimation could be wild in different ICUs. One option is not using the data which just starting with vent settings from the beginning. However, that would decrease your sample size.

Comment: Thank you for your first participation in open data StackExchange. It seems that your post will be more relevant as a comment to the previous answer (like this comment) rather than a dedicated answer. You can refer to this guide for how to answer: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/5782)

Answer (score 1):

generally not, because at least if my memory serves me correctly (and the database description doesn't fail me) MIMIC-III does not contain intraoperative ventilation times. Clinically speaking a lot of times the intubation occurs intraoperatively and  ICU-ventilation times start only later in a consecutive ICU-stay.